# Черную картинку заменять на белую при наведении

Tags: html, css

Какие есть способы замены черного изображения на белое с помощью css при `:hover`?

Использую такой способ (не очень хороший, потому как 2 изображения нужно загружать):

```css
.img {
  display: block;
}

.img_hover {
  display: none;
}

.box:hover .img {
  display: none;
}

.box:hover .img_hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=black" alt="" class="img">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/fff/000&text=white" alt="" class="img_hover">
</div>
```

Может быть есть способ с помощью фильтра или еще какие-нибудь варианты?
Картинка должна быть именно инлайновой (не фоном) и эффект должен быть максимально кроссбраузерным.

Comment: Мой вариант в IE не работает

Comment: @Grundy, а других похоже что и нет вариантов.

Comment: Вообще у IE были свои фильтры `DXImageTransform` например, но у меня они как-то не захотели работать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [фильтром `invert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#invert()_2)

```css
.img:hover {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=black" alt="" class="img">
</div>
```

Данный код не будет работать в IE (в EDGE все нормально), так как у него свои фильтры. Судя по справке для IE стиль должен использовать [фильтр BasicImage cо свойством invert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532893(v=vs.85).aspx)

Но у меня пример из справки не заработал:

```css
.img:hover {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(Invert=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=black" alt="" class="img">
</div>
```

[Так же указано](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx), что начиная с IE10 такие фильтры устаревшие и отключены по умолчанию.