# Возможно ли залить png изображение белым цветом средствами css?

Tags: css3

По умолчанию логотип красно-синий. Возможно ли средствами css залить изображение белым цветом?

[image: пример]

Comment: Такого сделать нельзя

Comment: Можете сделать прозрачный логотип с фоном соответствующим окружающему. А под ним средствами css вставлять всё что вздумается, если как в примере - синий и красный блоки

Comment: Менять цвет у png средствами css нельзя. Нужно логотип сделать в svg и тогда уже изменять цвет у всего, что угодно

Comment: @Cheg, Ну, откровенно говоря цвет у png через css поменять можно, через hue-rotate фильтр. Но вот в белый да, не получится

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686580/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Обязательно средствами CSS? я задавал похожий вопрос, [**как сделать это в GIMP, ImageMagick или Inkscape**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/74770/66040). Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так сделать можно. Вот [такой же вопрос с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623316/).

Например, можно с помощью `brightness(0)` получить полностью чёрную картинку и затем её [инвертировать](https://webref.ru/css/value/invert):

```
filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
```

```css
body { 
  background: #ccc;
}
img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.img-white {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
```

```html
<img alt="" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/SmAxl.png">
<img alt="" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/SmAxl.png" class="img-white">
```

Answer (score 0):

Это конечно шляпа так как само изображение я не залил цветом но так как img в png т.е имеет прозрачность можно залить под ним фон и вроде бы получается **визуальный обман** но за то без топорных методов

- what now ?
- stackoverflow

про переполнение стека : [оффтоп](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-A3Ac1WmAXF4/VRj_71TtxeI/AAAAAAAC0bQ/PyuZhg8fVXQ/s1600/stack-overflow.jpg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.logo img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.logo1 {
  background: green;
}

.logo2 {
  background: linear-gradient(tomato, blue, orange);
}
.logo3{
 background-color:#fff; outline:1px solid #f7f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://wordpress.omegastarinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/162098-albums5402-picture73610.png" alt="logo">
</div>

<div class="logo logo1">
  <img src="http://wordpress.omegastarinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/162098-albums5402-picture73610.png" alt="logo">
</div>

<div class="logo logo2">
  <img src="http://wordpress.omegastarinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/162098-albums5402-picture73610.png" alt="logo">
</div>

<div class="logo logo3"> 
  <img src="http://wordpress.omegastarinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/162098-albums5402-picture73610.png" alt="logo">
</div>
```

Comment: Так а где белый?)

Comment: @HamSter добавил вроде ! так пойдёт ?

Comment: ну да, правда, как по мне не совсем то что нужно